# Using jsonp with a tooltip in jQuery

Tags: tooltip, jsonp, jquery-tooltip

Anyone know of a good jQuery tooltip solution that allows for jsonp ajax requests?  I cant seem to get cluetip to work with jsonp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/table.html , you will have to use events to send ajax requests.